# plotting 3 column values in Matlab

Tags: plot

I have three column value which are 
x=[0    0.0100    0.0400    0.0900    0.1600    0.2500    0.3600    0.4900    0.6400    0.8100    1.0000]
y=[1.0000    0.8100    0.6400    0.4900    0.3600    0.2500    0.1600    0.0900    0.0400    0.0100         0]
z=[4.0000    4.0000    4.0205    4.1668    4.2506    4.2762    4.2506    4.1668    4.0205    4.0000    4.0000]
I want to plot them in 3D as a colored grid . anybody can help?

Comment: uhm. you have code? You want us to write the code for you? I will give you a great plot, in color, for $100 and a beer.